# Div with overflow auto last child's margin is being hidden in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div container with overflow: auto.  This div has two children that are dynamically populated ul elements by a third party JS library.  I have stripped down the resulting code as much as I could.

The problem I'm running into is in IE only (10+, not sure about other versions) the last child UL's margin-bottom is being pushed out of the view of the parent div.

UL in question:

```
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
```

css for UL

```
.pagination {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 .5% .5%;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

    .pagination > li {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 1%;
        padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
        background-color: #bbdefb;
    }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o3exrn5s/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't really show the problem, can you elaborate?

Comment: @garek007 if you use IE, the bottom margin of the pagination UL is pushed out of the parent div's view.

Comment: I don't have access to IE, but try position:relative; on .pagination